# Using TypeScript, how can I change interface based on the value of a property?

Tags: typescript

I want to enforce a property being present on an object as long as a specific value is being used for another property.

In the following example, I want the `backgroundSurfaceValue` to be required when the `variant` value is `ButtonVariant.Subtle`. I am trying to solve it using [Distributive Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) but I'm not doing something correctly. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Here's a link to the [code in the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAQmAu8D2IBqBDATgS3SeUA3gFBRQAKOEWAnlALxQDkl21mNTANKVAMrAAxigAmtBswHCQYjt158wAI3gAbYBKaKV6psQC%20xYvBoAHDdrXA4iFBhx4CjG8jRZc%20AHSX1R0JH4wTAAzdEFgDFUwDRIyRRCw4AAGTXjQ8KT5OKD04ABGVJzEvKzAhPCAJkLy4Aq9Q2MzDRcUSiRTAGcJH2sEV3sPAmAAD3hQES6WtwcvHt4AfiJeMjIAN3dHAC5YPrsN-ABuZZWlMIBrAHNMJDAZNMTI6O378MfgI5WVkHQIYG2O%20A4EAXD4rQxkbaxT5QdYzeDbKYDRygz6nQSXa63EQvCLoKJ-KAgYCrYCYFFfH4EgFAkHHfRHYjSAFQDrKKxTBG7EBtToSKGwwac2zTQbeNnqHhkNEYm53IqvPFPMq5N5imp5SWEynbLTi5pc%20T0oxMgimKi0Dk7YU8rqMfn7eFW-oOzysdg0TXfX46t3iKaGg5AA).

```js
enum ButtonVariant {
  Primary = 'Primary',
  Secondary = 'Secondary',
  Subtle = 'Subtle'
}

type SubtleButtonVariant = ButtonVariant.Subtle

enum SurfaceValue {
  Surface0 = 'Surface0',
  Surface1 = 'Surface1',
  Surface2 = 'Surface2'
}

type ButtonProps = SubtleButtonVariant extends ButtonVariant.Subtle
  ? {
      variant: ButtonVariant;
      backgroundSurfaceValue: SurfaceValue;
      name: string;
    }
  : {
      variant: ButtonVariant;
      backgroundSurfaceValue: never;
      name: string;
    };

const subtleButton: ButtonProps = {
  variant: ButtonVariant.Subtle,
  backgroundSurfaceValue: SurfaceValue.Surface1,
  name: 'Subtle Button',
};

const primaryButton: ButtonProps = {
  variant: ButtonVariant.Primary,
  name: 'Primary Button',
};
```

Comment: Are you maybe instead looking for a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NaDQow)? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That looks great! Seems to do exactly what I'm looking for! Please write up the answer and I'll select it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `ButtonProps` object to have a `variant` property, whose [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) can be used to *discriminate* which of several shapes the whole object has.  That indicates you really want `ButtonProps` to be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type, as follows:

```
type ButtonProps = {
  variant: ButtonVariant.Subtle;
  backgroundSurfaceValue: SurfaceValue;
  name: string;
} | {
  variant: Exclude<ButtonVariant, ButtonVariant.Subtle>;
  backgroundSurfaceValue?: never;
  name: string;
};
```

If the `variant` prop is `ButtonVariant.Subtle`, then `backgroundSurfaceValue` is required and must be of type `SurfaceValue`.

Otherwise, if the `variant` prop is either `ButtonVariant.Primary` or  `ButtonVariant.Secondary` (which is represented above as `Exclude<ButtonVariant, ButtonVariant.Subtle>` via [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers)), then `backgroundSurfaceValue` is essentially prohibited, being an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), meaning the only value you could possibly read from it is `undefined`.

Let's test that out:

```
const subtleButton: ButtonProps = {
  variant: ButtonVariant.Subtle,
  backgroundSurfaceValue: SurfaceValue.Surface1,
  name: 'Subtle Button',
};

const primaryButton: ButtonProps = {
  variant: ButtonVariant.Primary,
  name: 'Primary Button',
};

const badButton: ButtonProps = { // error! 
  //  ~~~~~~~~~ <-- Property 'backgroundSurfaceValue' is missing
  variant: ButtonVariant.Subtle,
  name: 'Bad Button'
}

const alsoBadButton: ButtonProps = { // error!
  //  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Type 'SurfaceValue' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
  variant: ButtonVariant.Secondary,
  backgroundSurfaceValue: SurfaceValue.Surface2
  name: 'Also Bad Button'
}
```

Looks good.

---

Note that your version had several problems which prevented it from working as desired:

It wasn't actually a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) because the checked type `SubtleButtonVariant` is not a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter; it's a specific type, equivalent to `ButtonVariant.Subtle`.  That's just a regular conditional type, which will evaluate to the true branch alone (since `SubtleButtonVariant extends ButtonVariant.Subtle` is always true).

For it to be distributive, you'd have needed to write something like

```
type ButtonProps<T extends ButtonVariant> = T extends ButtonVariant.Subtle
    ? {
  variant: ButtonVariant;
  backgroundSurfaceValue: SurfaceValue;
  name: string;
} : {
  variant: ButtonVariant;
  backgroundSurfaceValue: never;
  name: string;
};
```

but that wouldn't be a type you could just assign to a variable without specifying the input type parameter.  The whole point of distributive conditional types is to *distribute* some type operation across [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in their inputs.  So you need to give it a union.

You could have fixed *that* by either specifying it in another type

```
  type BProps = ButtonProps<ButtonVariant>;
```

or by having `T` [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `ButtonVariant`:

```
type ButtonProps<T extends ButtonVariant = ButtonVariant> = 
  T extends ButtonVariant.Subtle ? {
    variant: ButtonVariant;
    backgroundSurfaceValue: SurfaceValue;
    name: string;
  } : {
    variant: ButtonVariant;
    backgroundSurfaceValue: never;
    name: string;
  };
```

Either way would produce a new union type:

```
/* type ButtonProps = {
  variant: ButtonVariant;
  backgroundSurfaceValue: SurfaceValue;
  name: string;
 } | {
  variant: ButtonVariant;
  backgroundSurfaceValue: never;
  name: string;
 }*/
```

But of course, that still doesn't work... the `variant` property is the same on both halves of the union, so there's nothing to discriminate.  Also, the `backgroundSurfaceValue` property on one of the union members is a *required* property of type `never`, which is impossible.  If we fix both of those we get:

```
type ButtonProps = {
  variant: ButtonVariant.Subtle;
  backgroundSurfaceValue: SurfaceValue;
  name: string;
} | {
  variant: Exclude<ButtonVariant, ButtonVariant.Subtle>;
  backgroundSurfaceValue?: never;
  name: string;
};
```

That is, you get a discriminated union again.  There might be some reason why you'd want to use a generic conditional type for `ButtonProps`, but it's not obvious from the example.  For the question as asked, you should just use a discriminated union instead of a conditional type, distributive or otherwise.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-mPUu2j2w3hS2zyZWq3W2Y2Wx-Wx2uwAVRrIJIshOcIIHHScqXoHgQCgWd1lAax7CQBgkP-GQcQgQJ6QgHQD0jRdCyFKZZlFEwxHXQdsTNID8SOUdLTtICyj4FNpAAQQwM8qF3fcPAlalYBCbt6AQiAwAAeRJd5+AaJp-DdBVCO4AwFN1O03QlIgZPdENbwMVcVIRYg-hoEgdC6AzhTU+YLCIAkpOiPCEWveFhUpI01iHHE8UtWjqMtNynU3Wk7geGzDwcpARgjByo2GAjdQC9EPMokc-JA4lSXJRKNyuGU6QZMLvVqPjNwExAhJEsAfwAd3oXgLC0wtQxBH8jJMkxzI9RSaGRAxWogYzTM6uFuqs+wwrs6KPnwiypmyijh289LrRCfFspTG4QoC54orCxzNXihF5uSxa6OWkkyQpPacqtTa522ylGsoYspGVW8wS63VUTrAAqFDZOe3TwzC2KaGc7qAoWryzsOFaLRAgKNvy0KHOeN4pqQUHwYSsKoaom0fKpTKroipGtps9wfuZLxeOY0q4HK9pKp-AALVgIEiDT-u08Zmv6waOsO4VlM+hFeokML+fasyhaI1ckEm66sdl7hjsxTz8dWwmlrOa6yfuwrIvsmKZtF1zrrx1KCfO4n1qCvLyYi70GtQwGOjvN73cpZk-qel7jf26NZtV3GTuhtLYZ1xYwv1grUdeAPMdNkacYiy2o4yy7Eftu64+iSnqYlOp3CAA)

Comment: Wow! Such a wealth of knowledge! Thanks so much!